# How can we improve speed of Python reading from AS400 tables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, db2, ibm-midrange

We're working on a data ingestion tool in Python and facing slowness while reading from (multiple) AS400 tables.

This is the core portion of the tool (specific to reading of AS400 tables). As you can see, it's not doing much; it merely reads the table from AS400 database, adds a timestamp column to it, and writes it to another target database, which, in this case, resides in MS SQL Server.

```
def process(record):
    engine_source = new_as400_connection()
    engine_destination = new_db_connection()
    ROWS = 100_000
    
    df_gen = pd.read_sql(record.query, engine_source, chunksize=ROWS)
    for df in df_gen:
        df['_ETLDate'] = pd.to_datetime('today').replace(microsecond=0)
        df.to_sql(
            record.target,
            engine_destination,
            if_exists='append',
            index=False,
        )
    
    engine_source.dispose()
    engine_destination.dispose()
```

Here's how we're calling this function using the built-in `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(16) as executor:
        __ = executor.map(process, records)
```

where `records` is a list of tables to be processed, which looks like this:

```
┌───────────┬───────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ source_id │  target   │                 query                  │
├───────────┼───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ TABLE001  │ target_01 │ SELECT * FROM TABLE001                 │
│ TABLE002  │ target_02 │ SELECT * FROM TABLE002                 │
│ TABLE003  │ target_03 │ SELECT * FROM TABLE003 WHERE ABC > 100 │
└───────────┴───────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The idea is, obviously, to copy data from AS400 to SQL Server in parallel. However, this approach is slower than equivalent jobs executed using SSIS packages. The difference is very significant: this Python code takes almost 3x-4x more time than SSIS packages do (even when the latter are executed sequentially).

Things we tried:

- Use multi-processing. Not surprised that it didn't help, as this is supposed to be an I/O intensive operation.
- Check AS400 documentation: extremely useless.
- Multiple threads within each thread - by trying to read, say, row #1 - #10K in one thread, next 10K rows in another, and so on. Not much of a difference.
- The SQL Server resides in Azure environment, while the AS400 databases reside in an on-premises server. The Python tool was initially being executed from the Azure VM, and we thought moving the code execution to on-premises server will help. Surprisingly, it took a little longer than the execution in the Azure VM server.
- Fetch all rows at once instead of batches of 100K. It didn't help, but occasionally, some large tables would cause memory errors and Python would crash.
- Run all tables sequentially rather than in parallel. Only took a bit longer than the multi-threaded approach (not surprised).
- We're also using another similar package in which, instead of using DataFrames, we're using `pyodbc`'s `cursor.fetchmany`. That performs almost the same as this one. So, we believe this drastic slowness is not due to using `pandas.read_sql`.

A colleague suggested invoking the copying process of each table in a separate process in a subshell. So, we switched from the multi-threading approach to this *child-process* approach:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.single_record:
        process(json.loads(record))
    else:
        cmd = './venv/Scripts/python -m sourcetostaging --single_record'
        for record in records:
            subprocess.Popen(
                [*cmd.split(), json.dumps(record)],
                cwd='./',
                stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            )
```

It worked well: we saw an improvement of around 60%-70%. However, this code was still slower than the SSIS packages: this modified approach took twice as much time as the SSIS packages (even when the latter were executed sequentially).

We understand that since SSIS uses SQL, it'll always be faster than equivalent Python code. However, 2x more time seems to indicate that there must be something wrong I'm doing in the Python code.

Here are the connection strings we're using:

```
def new_as400_connection():
    cs = 'ibm_db_sa+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + quote(
        'DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};'
        + 'SYSTEM={system};UID={uid};PWD={pwd}'.format(**config_as400)
    )
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(cs)


def new_db_connection():
    cs = 'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pwd}@{host}/{database}?driver={driver}'
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        cs.format(**config_db),
        fast_executemany=True,
    )
```

Is there any other approach we're overlooking? We thought the multi-threaded approach is pretty common one.

Notes

- Both Python and SSIS are using the same set of configurations (Compression = True, etc.)
- We have tried profiling this code to see where the bottleneck is: not surprised that `for df in df_gen:` (or `cursor.fetchmany` in another package) is the most time consuming of all.

Comment: If you want your solution to near equal the performance of the proprietary SSIS solution then your design need to be similar or better than the proprietary design as regards bulk I/O.

Comment: @mao, sounds fair. Any resources you'd suggest that'd help me in learning such better designs related to parallelism, bulk I/O, etc.?

Comment: Study the docs for your Db2 client software, examine what bulk export and bulk unload functionality exists, and what options exist to optimise network traffic during export/unload. Sometimes unloading to flat-files (or pipes) and transforming those, before native-bulk loads to the target is the fastest approach.

Comment: Since Db2 is the source, it's unlikely to be your issue.  I'd look at how the rows are being inserted into the destination.  Does your SSIS package use bulk inserts?  Or otherwise insert multiple rows at once?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is the performance problem has to do with ODBC.

I would code a web service that returns a subset of the rows of a table by key.  Here is PHP code that reads rows from a product master by customer code. You can code a similar web service in python or node.

An advantage of a web service is you can code it specifically for the tables you are reading. If reading the entire inventory file you can start at an item number and then `fetch first 50000 rows only`.  When reading the next batch the client can tell the server web service where to starting reading from.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset:utf-8;");

$cucode = isset($_GET["cucode"]) ? $_GET["cucode"]: '' ; 

$sql = 'select    a.prcucd, a.prprcd, a.prdes1, a.prdes2 ' . 
        'from     prmast a ' . 
        "where    ( ? = ' ' or a.prcucd = ? ) " ; 
$libl = 'qgpl qtemp' ;
$conn = as400Connect( $libl ) ;                    
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);                          
   
db2_bind_param( $stmt, 1, "cucode", DB2_PARAM_IN ) ;       
db2_bind_param( $stmt, 2, "cucode", DB2_PARAM_IN ) ;       
                                                           
$result = as400Execute($stmt, $sql) ;

$ar1 = array( ) ;
while( $row = db2_fetch_assoc( $stmt ))
{
  $ar1[] = $row ;
}

echo json_encode($ar1);                          `          

 
// ---------------------------- as400Connect ------------------------
function as400Connect( $libl )
{
  $options = array('i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON);  
  if (strlen($libl) > 0)
  {
    $options['i5_libl'] = $libl ;
  }
  $conn = db2_connect("*LOCAL","","", $options);
  if (!$conn) {
    echo "Connection failed" ;
    echo "<br>" ;
    echo db2_conn_errormsg( ) ;
    exit( ) ;
  }
  return $conn ;
}

// ------------------------- as400Execute --------------------------
function as400Execute( $stmt, $sql = null )
{
  $result = db2_execute($stmt) ;
  if (!$result) {
    echo '<br>' . 'the db2 execute failed. ' ;
    echo '<br>' . ' SQLSTATE: ' . db2_stmt_error( ) ;
    echo '<br>' . ' message: ' . db2_stmt_errormsg( ) ;
    if       (is_null($sql) == false )
      echo '<br>' . $sql ;

  // write to the php error log.
    $fullText = 'db2_execute failed. sqlstate:' . db2_stmt_error( ) .
                ' message: ' . db2_stmt_errormsg( ) ;
    if       (is_null($sql) == false )
      $fullText   = $fullText . ' ' . $sql ;
    error_log( $fullText ) ;
    error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), TRUE));
  }

return     $result ;
}

?>
```